# Pass data from 3 plist files using custom URL scheme

Tags: iphone, migration, plist, url-scheme

I have a Lite and Full apps. I need to pass the data from 3 plist files which are in Documents folder of the app (Lite), to the new (Full) app. I understand it can be done with custom URL scheme. Can someone explain the process of exporting/importing the data?

Can anyone confirm that this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the sandbox environment on iOS, an application is only able to access its own `Documents` folder. This means your Full app cannot access files (in your case the `.plist` files) from the Lite's `Documents` folder.

Comment: I understan that. But apparently this can be done using custom URL scheme, or am I wrong?